# Dota 2 Reborn: Stop Console Command

Tags: dota-2

I am trying to build an alias that would allow me to use a single key to do the attack jitter.

This is what I've tried:

bind a `+attackmacro`

alias `+attackmacro "dota_stop"`

alias `-attackmacro "mc_attack"`

Unfortunately, the console spits out dota_stop not recognized (even though it shows up when you direct enter in the console".  It will perform the attack but wont do the stop.

Anyone know what the new stop console command is or how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't think that scripting is allowed

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to replicate the action of cancelling your attack (e.g. stop the right click) you can try [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com).

Autohotkey allows for custom keys binds and macros, the most common of which, unsuprisingly, is used for Invoker's spells.

Some mouses also come bundled with software that can remap certain buttons to a macro function. An example of which is Corsair's Utility Engine.

If you are looking to do it purely through console, I believe there are restrictions. There has been talks about how scripting fall into a grey area in competitive gaming, the most notable of which is the "Armlet Toggle" bind, giving players a small HP increase in a fraction of a second.

It was patched soon after, so take that as you will.